# Undefined vertexUv warning

Tags: three.js

I exported a 3D model from sketchup to collada and used Threejs Collada loader to load it. But I get the following warnings:

```
THREE.DirectGeometry.fromGeometry(): Undefined vertexUv 2
```

It appears that some meshes in my collada model have 4 faces but only 2 UV values. Any ideas why collada has missing UV values? And is there a workaround in Threejs with loading such models?

In version 71 of threejs library this used to be just a warning, but in version 72 this results in the following error when using picking:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (12:59:20:764 | error, javascript)
    at raycast (public_html/libs/three.js:17237:19)
    at intersectObject (public_html/libs/three.js:7678:10)
    at intersectObject (public_html/libs/three.js:7686:5)
    at intersectObject (public_html/libs/three.js:7686:5)
    at intersectObject (public_html/libs/three.js:7686:5)
    at THREE.Raycaster.intersectObject (public_html/libs/three.js:7734:4)
    at adjustCameraPositionForCollision (public_html/PointerLockControls.js:302:86)
    at update (public_html/PointerLockControls.js:257:14)
    at render (public_html/simbuilding.js:113:24)
```

Comment: Did you try to load the model in Blender, add an UV map, and export it (to collada or something else ?)

Comment: It's been a while so I don't exactly recall what I ended up doing about this problem. I think I ended up just deleting the culprit polygons. Those polygons were so small that deleting them didn't cause any visual problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to assign Uvs to your geometry

```
  assignUVs(geometry) {
    geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry.mergeVertices();
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];
    geometry.faces.forEach((face) => {
      const components = ['x', 'y', 'z'].sort((a, b) => {
        return Math.abs(face.normal[a]) > Math.abs(face.normal[b]);
      });
      const v1 = geometry.vertices[face.a];
      const v2 = geometry.vertices[face.b];
      const v3 = geometry.vertices[face.c];
      geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
        new THREE.Vector2(v1[components[0]], v1[components[1]]),
        new THREE.Vector2(v2[components[0]], v2[components[1]]),
        new THREE.Vector2(v3[components[0]], v3[components[1]])
      ]);
    });
    geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
    return geometry;
  }
```